# How can I set the same keyframe for multiple objects but with an interval?

Tags: keyframes

I have around 200 objects and I want to assign the same location keyframe to all of them, but I want every keyframe to be 1 keyframe later than the last one. For example if the first keyframe is at frame 100, the next one is at frame 101 then 102 and so on. I played around with Timeline and Graphic Editor but couldn't find anything, please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: search for free commotion add-on

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks